# parity of the number of non-isomorphic graphs with $v$ vertices

Tags: graph-theory

I'm reading Richard J. Trudeau's book "[Introduction to Graph Theory](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Graph-Theory-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486678709)", in page 54 it listed out the number of non-isomorphic graphs, given vertices $v$:

> V: number of graphs
>
> 1: 1
>
> 2: 2
>
> 3: 4
>
> 4: 11
>
> 5: 34
>
> 6: 156
>
> 7: 1,044
>
> 8: 12,346
>
> 9: 308, 708

Then in exercise 27 it asks:

> In the table on page 54, the numbers in the second column are mostly
> even. If we ignore the first row on the ground that v = 1 is such a
> trivial situation that its uniqueness is unremarkable, that leaves v =
> 4 as the only number of vertices listed for which there are an
> odd number of graphs. Do you think this is due to chance, or can you
> think of some reason why v = 4 should be unique? If the table were
> continued, do you think more odd numbers would turn up in the second
> column?

I'm a bit lost here. There number of $v$ vertices graphs (in the sense of non-isomorphic) is quite huge and I don't see a way to determine if it's even or odd.

The key, i guess, is the self-complementary graphs. However, given vertices number $v$, there might be multiple self-complementary graphs, e.g. $v=5$ has 2.

Pls enlighten me.